# Transfer some photos/videos from one iPhone to another

Tags: iphone, photos, data-transfer, import

I want to add some photos and videos from someone else’s iPhone to my iPhone’s photo library.

I want to keep the photo’s dates so that they appear at the right time chronologically in my library.

I know I can airdrop but I don’t think that saves the date? Rather just adds them to the end of your photo library.

Usually I would plug their phone into my Mac and import using Photos, but this isn’t possible.

Is there a way of doing this importing of photos directly from one iPhone to another?

Comment: Did you try with AirDrop? Are both phones using iCloud Photo Library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AirDrop will transfer the meta data - showing the date of the photo, location, etc.

If you go to the Photos app, select Albums, and then All Photos, it will naturally show at the bottom of the list as it is the most recent photo to be added to the phone. *However* if you select Photos, instead of Albums, it will be sorted chronologically by date.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SHAREIt](https://itunes.apple.com/app/shareit-connect-transfer/id725215120) app which allows you to transfer photos from one device to another. I use it quite often and would recommend it. This keeps all the MetaData intact.